# how do you JOIN two tables without using common column?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Table 1                               Table 2

Column1    Column2    Column3         Column4    Column5    Column3
-------    -------    -------         -------    -------    -------
A          1          a               E          10         a
B          2          b               F          11         b
C          3          c               G          12         c
D          4          d               H          13         d


Table 3                               Table 4  

Column6    Column7    Column4         Column8    Column9    Column6
-------    -------    -------         -------    -------    -------
I          20         E               M          30         I
J          21         F               N          31         J
K          22         G               O          32         K
L          23         H               P          33         L
```

Expected Output

```
Column1    Column9
-------    -------
C          31
C          32
C          33
```

How do I get the output to look at the expected above?

This is for my Oracle SQL course I am currently taking. Although the tables have common columns, the question ask **NOT** to use the common columns and instead use a different column to get the expected output while getting rid of duplicates.

Comment: what have you tried so far..? Also if you are using Oracle, do not tag mysql,sql-server etc.

Comment: what is realation of data tables ? why column 1 you want only C ?

Comment: I need to select a specific person from column1 and the books they bought from column9. The person in column1 may have multiple purchases.

Comment: *HOW* did you manually arrive at the answer? `Try to describe what you did please.` I don't see how column 1 value 'C' traces to Column 9 values 31, 32 and 33

Comment: so column1: C = (name of person) and column9: 31, 32, 33 = (book title 1, book title 2, book title 3)

and I know its confusing, I don't even know where to start since the question won't let me use common columns

Comment: Why doesn't the data model use `person` and `book` and other meaningful names? If this is your naming please **edit your question** to make it clearer. If this is how your Oracle course actually presents the question then I suggest you find a different course immediately.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Those common columns are called foreign keys. No one would ask you to come up with a result set that completely ignored the keys. Are you sure you are reading the problem right?

Answer (score 0):

Given the posted structure, this statement ...

```
 select tableA.column1
        , tableD.column9
 from tableA
      cross join tableD
 where tableA.column1 = 'C'
 and tableD.column9 > 30
```

... will produce the expected output. Obviously it doesn't make sense as a query, so it is an apt answer for the question.

**Note:**  If the OP edits their question with a proper data model and realistic data then of course I will edit my answer to be something more sensible.

Comment: thanks for the help but I found the answer, also I did listed common columns which are column3 (table1, table2), column4 (table2, table3), column6 (table3, table4)

Comment: So if the answer isn't joining on those columns what is it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I needed to create a report and just combined two different tables in to one. The easiest and don't require a JOIN.

SELECT table1.column1, table4.column9
FROM table1, table4
WHERE column1 = 'c'

Comment: `FROM table1, table4` is CROSS JOIN!